# Multiple OpenVPN sharing an external IP/port

Tags: vpn

Situation: we need to have multiple OpenVPN (or equivalent) services that are accessible via port 443 externally. In an *ideal* world we would like them all to share a single external IP address divert their traffic to their respective the subnet(s) they support. "Corporate" IT is frowning on granting us multiple externally accessible IP addresses so we're looking for some avenue to share the one that we currently have between several VPN services.

We can't co-mingle the VPN traffic for security reasons - hence the need for multiple, independent VPN services.

Im imagining some (possibly hypothetical) service that would listen at port 443 and route the VPN traffic based on the internal private subnet that each VPN is serving. Once the traffic was 'internal' to our network it could go to whatever host / service / port necessary.

I don't know if this is feasible or practical but for some reason I feel like it should be possible. Can anyone suggest a method to do this?

Comment: A single OpenVPN server can isolate all users from each other and give unique routing tables to each user. A few extra firewall rules on the VPN server just for extra assurance, and Bob's your uncle. PS, I hope your IPv6 deployment is well underway.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this is sslh found at https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh and probably already available in your distribution.

It allows you to use one single port on a single address to accept connections and forward them to different destinations. The name is derived from the ability to use SSL and SSH on the same port, but it allows to distinguish on different properties, one of them is the SNI of the SSL handshake. The target can be any port on the local host or on a different host.

So all you need it to get multiple DNS names all pointing to your IP address, which should not be that difficult.